# Vim unnamed register + or *

Tags: vim

Im using Vim 7.3 in Ubuntu and I'm having a little problem copying to the system clipboard with the following command `"+y` but I'm getting the following error: `E354: Invalid register name: '+'`

In my `vim --version`, I see `-xterm_clipboard`. The option to copy is from mouse right click is also grayed out.

What steps do I need to take to enable the copying of text from my vim to the system clipboard?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Trivial problem, sir.

```
sudo aptitude install vim-gnome
```

which already comes pre-compiled with the +xterm_clipboard option.

On source-based distros like gentoo, you will have to compile the package with this USE flag specified.

Answer (score 10):

You should see `+xterm_clipboard`.

The simplest fix is to install a version of vim compiled with clipboard support. In Ubuntu, if you don't wish to build your own, you can install `vim-gtk` or `vim-gnome`, both of which have clipboard support.

Answer (score 1):

For Arch Linux, install `gvim`. This also adds the missing feature to `vim`.